# Making a layout in AndoidStudio

Tags: android-layout

New to Android development, but lots of experience in C#, Winforms, Webforms, and MVC.

It's making absolutely no sense whatsoever. I've done the tutorials but I just don't know how to get started or what to do.

I need to make a layout that looks something like this.

[image]

Easy in Winforms: some group boxes and lots of labels.
Easy in HTML: a `div` with a border and a `position:relative` for the label and a table inside.

What on Earth does on do in Android?

Comment: How much area will those going to cover? What elements/widgets are these? TextViews? Layouts? What are these values? just random values or these much iterations of a widget? What are those texts? Also, I'd suggest you to go with `ConstrainLayout` as this is one of the most advanced layouts and is easy to learn. Ask me anything about Android Layouts, I'll help.

Comment: I've got as far as a vertical `LinearLayout` containing a `GridLayout` and each column in the first row is a `LinearLayout` that contains a `TextView` for `Thing1` and a `GridLayout` with three columns.
What a mess.
I can't work out how to move the `TextView` for `Thing 1` up into the `LinearLayout`'s border. I seem to think it should be something to do with `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: `LinearLayout` horizonal with `weightSum` seems like a simpler way to make the columns?

Comment: Well you can directly use gridlayouts for things1 ,things2 ,things3 which are placed inside a relative layout.

Comment: Share the code. I'll fix it and explain it to you.